# What sort of animals are PushTopics?

Tags: pushtopic

We have verified that PushTopic exhibit a strange behaviour: if you have a PushTopic with a given name in your org, and you try to insert a PushTopic with the same name in a test, you get a failure.

```
@isTest
public class PushTopicsTest {

    @isTest
    public static void testPushTopicsConfigurationIsValid(){
        Test.startTest();
        PushTopics.upsertPushTopics();
        Test.stopTest();
        Map<Id,PushTopic> expected = new Map<Id,PushTopic>(PushTopics.getPushTopics());
        Map<Id,PushTopic> observed = new Map<Id,PushTopic>([Select  ApiVersion,
                                                                    Id, 
                                                                    Name, 
                                                                    NotifyForFields,
                                                                    Query
                                                                    from PushTopic ]);
        System.assertEquals(expected.size(),observed.size());
        for(Id pushTopicId : observed.keySet()){
            System.assertEquals(observed.get(pushTopicId), expected.get(pushTopicId));
        }                                                                             
    }
}
```

What we discovered is that if we run in anonymous window `PushTopics.upsertPushTopics()` and then we run this test, this test fails even if `upsertPushTopics()` is idempotent, because it doesn't see the real data on the org. However, if we annotate `testPushTopicsConfigurationIsValid()` with `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` then the test succeed.

PushTopics obviously have a strange persistence model, what are the characteristics/tricks of this model and what other objects share the same model?